# wizard bootstrap return current tab

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, wizard

I implemented in my application the wizard bootstrap .

I want to retrieve the index of the Current tab to test 
a display or hide the buttons 'Next' 'Previous'

---

```
$('#rootwizard').bootstrapWizard({
    'nextSelector': '.button-next',
    'previousSelector': '.button-previous',
    onTabClick: function (tab, navigation, index) {
        var total = navigation.find('li').length;

        // here i want get the currecnt index of tab clicked 
        var current = index +1 ;
        alert();

        // set wizard title
        $('.step-title', $('#rootwizard')).text('Step ' + (index) + ' of ' + total);

        // set done steps
        jQuery('li', $('#rootwizard')).removeClass("done");
        var li_list = navigation.find('li');

        for (var i = 0; i < index; i++) {
             jQuery(li_list[i]).addClass("done");
        }
        if (current == 1) {
            $('#rootwizard').find('.button-previous').hide();
        } else {
            $('#rootwizard').find('.button-previous').show();
        }
        if (current >= 13) {
            $('#rootwizard').find('.button-next').hide();
            $('#rootwizard').find('.button-submit').show();
        } else {
            $('#rootwizard').find('.button-next').show();
            $('#rootwizard').find('.button-submit').hide();
        }
        App.scrollTo($('.page-title'));
```

The HTML:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">                               
    <li class=" active" id="dbt"><a href="#portlet_tab1" data-toggle="tab">aaa</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#portlet_tab2" data-toggle="tab">   bbb   </a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#portlet_tab3" data-toggle="tab">   ccc   </a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#portlet_tab4" data-toggle="tab">    dddd    </a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 5):

To show the index from $(document).ready() or another function in your code:

```
alert( $('#rootwizard').bootstrapWizard('currentIndex') );
```

In your case, when creating the wizard, you forgot the single quotes when declaring the 'onTabClick' function. Anyways, I recommend you to use the event 'onTabShow' instead:

```
$('#rootwizard').bootstrapWizard({
'nextSelector': '.button-next',
'previousSelector': '.button-previous',
'onTabShow': function (tab, navigation, index) {
    var total = navigation.find('li').length;

    // here i want get the currecnt index of tab clicked 
    var current = index + 1 ;
    alert(current);

    // set wizard title --> CHANGED 'index' by 'current'
    $('.step-title', $('#rootwizard')).text('Step ' + (current) + ' of ' + total);

    // set done steps
    jQuery('li', $('#rootwizard')).removeClass("done");
    var li_list = navigation.find('li');

    for (var i = 0; i < index; i++) {
         jQuery(li_list[i]).addClass("done");
    }
    if (current == 1) {
        $('#rootwizard').find('.button-previous').hide();
    } else {
        $('#rootwizard').find('.button-previous').show();
    }
    if (current >= 13) {
        $('#rootwizard').find('.button-next').hide();
        $('#rootwizard').find('.button-submit').show();
    } else {
        $('#rootwizard').find('.button-next').show();
        $('#rootwizard').find('.button-submit').hide();
    }
    App.scrollTo($('.page-title'));
```

I'm a bit late, I know, but I hope it can help others.

Comment: what if i want to prevent the user from visiting tab index 4, I would need to use the onClick but the onclick returns the previous tab index